# When to Use sendEvent in Services vs. Actions in Spring State Machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am currently working with Spring State Machine and facing a design decision about the optimal placement of the sendEvent method. I understand that it can be used both in services and actions, but I'm seeking practical examples or use cases to better understand when to use each approach.

Could you provide examples or scenarios where:

**Using sendEvent in Services is more advantageous?**

**Using sendEvent in Actions is preferable?**

I'm trying to discern the best practices for these approaches, keeping in mind the principles of separation of concerns, maintainability, and readability of the code. Insights into real-world applications and examples where one method is favored over the other would be incredibly helpful.